# objective-c uitableview when does dequeing cells not make sense

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, deque

I know the general guideline is to dequeue cells as they go off the screen in a uitableviewcell.

I would think this recommendation/guideline is relaxed when you have the uitableview acting as a form and have possibly different types of uitableviewcells in there.

e.g. label/textfield, label/uiswitch, label/label/uidatepicker.

Such a tableview in my case has been limited to 4-5 cells.

Do we need to worry about dequeing form based (4-5 cells) tableviews?

What do y'all do when faced with a tableview with different types of cells in it?

Answer (score 1):

For every type of cell you will use a different identifier.
In you case, with 4 or 5 cells, it will not have a big impact on performances if you don't follow the guidelines.

These guidelines must be followed when you scroll a lot of cells.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Question, if you used multiple cell identifiers, how would you know which one is going off the screen in order to put the dequeue request?

Comment: You don't have to know which one is going off, all you need to know is which kind of cell you need, so you put your dequeue request and if no cell found you create a new one of this kind